# c# Open Default browser with a link and wait for a response

Tags: c#, facebook, url, browser

The problem is I will open a link (facebook login) and wait for the user to login then get whats written after. The link will be open by c# desktop app/WinForms.

I have done what I want to achieve using webbrowser but the user will login again on facebook even though they are logged in already (example in chrome).

When I'm installing adobe photoshop I have seen this feature.

Comment: The WebBrowser Control is utilizing Internet Explorer, so when the user is logged in to facebook using Chrome. The Internet Explorer doesnt know this. In fact i dont think the WebBrowser Control will know any cookies from the real Internet Explorer either. I am pretty sure Adobe is using Chrome to show Webcontent, so maybe they share cookies...

Comment: Hello yes that's what I want to learn sir, I want to know what are the techniques used to do that